# Dust on image, using alpha node on a mask

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I would like to add some dust on my character, with the "add" option selected, the dust becomes white instead of black.

I tried to use "subtract" for a second attempt but I can't find out how to make the dust less visible, I would like a smooth effect like an old picture, here the black dots are too much. The alpha node does not seem to work with "subtract".

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alpha over and Math nodes

When you want to overlay an image with transparency to another, the **[Alpha over](https://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/color/alpha_over.html)** node is perhaps a better coiche than any other node.

From the manual's page:

> Use this node to layer images on top of one another.

---

Example of usage:

[image]

Note that you don't even need to set the overlayed image's alpha, it is already taken into account.

[image]

One of the possible way to control the strenght of the mix could be lowering the incoming overlaying factor with a **Math node**:

[image]

While before the range of the factor was from 0 to 1, now are linearly remapped from 0 to 0.4, resulting in a softer effect.

[image]